# Is there a structure that can discriminate between two isomorphic Lie groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-derivative

I have been learning about Lie groups and there is a question that has been in the back of my mind for a while. I will try to formulate it with an analogy. On a differential manifold with a metric structure, the metric structure induces an isomorphism between vectors and 1-forms (the musical isomorphisms). Yet, we have a natural structure (here I use natural to indicate that its definition does not necessitate any additional assumption other than the manifold being a differentiable one), the Lie derivative, that can distinguish between vectors and 1-forms. In other words, for a general metric, the Lie derivative and the musical isomorphism do not commute. Is there something similar for Lie groups? For example, SO(2) and U(1) are isomorphic. So are they really distinct groups? In other words, is there a way to distinguish them or are they just representations of the same abstract group?

I guess my question is what exactly uniquely defines a group? What natural (as defined above) structures can be used to differentiate abstract groups?

Comment: SO(3) and SU(2) are not isomorphic as Lie Groups, the former is not simply connected while the latter is.

Comment: Perhaps a better example would be $U(1)$, $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$, and $SO(2)$? These are isomorphic as lie groups (they're all $S^1$) but might have some external property that distinguishes them based on their constructions.

Comment: Isomorphic Lie algebras is a necessary, but not sufficient condition. It is both necessary and sufficient in the case of *simply connected* Lie groups, but without that requirement you need to use a bit of covering space theory.

Comment: I have edited the example to SO(2) and U(1). The question remains